# PCRE matching whole words in a string

Tags: php, pcre

I'm trying to run a regexp in php (`preg_match_all`) that matches certain whole words in a string, but problem is that it also matches words that contain only part of a tested word.
Also this is a sub-query in a larger regexp, so other PHP functions like `strpos` won't help me, sadly.

*String*: `"I test a string"`

*Words to match*: `"testable", "string"`

*Tried regexp*: `/([testable|string]+)/`

*Expected result*: `"string"` only!

*Result*: `"test", "a", "string"`

Comment: Your regex is exactly equivalent to `/([abegilnrst|]+)/`

Comment: thanks, I got it solved now... but why did you delete your answer?:D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you really want to make sure you only get your words and not words that contain them, then you can use word boundary anchors:

```
/\b(testable|string)\b/
```

This will match only a word boundary followed by either `testable` or `string` and then another word boundary.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want a character class with `[]`, you just want to match the words:

`/testable|string/`